# Get device ID FOR api 21 above

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anyone tell me how to fetch the device Id for above api 21 .. i want to fetch  both the device id if its dual sim ??

Currently I am using below code

```
public static String getImeiNumber(Context context) {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (telephonyManager != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Device ID" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
                return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and also above marshmallow how can i get the device ID WITH DUAL SIM ???

Comment: what you actually want phone nmbr or deviceid?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) question please.

Comment: DeviceId has nothing to do with sim card. It is a unique number of the phone. You mention dual sim, what exactly do you need to get?

Comment: I got the answer ..Thank You.. @Vucko device Id is nothing but the imei ID and dual sim has two imei's .. thats what i wanted ... found ans here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29